# How to fix this python telnet code to send a command to a device a second time?

Tags: python, telnet

Under windows 10 and using python 3.10.11 I am trying to run a command on a telnet-connected device twice. The problem is that only the first time it works and the second time the command is only half(?) transmitted to the device?

First, here is the complete code:

```
import time
import telnetlib

def read(session, timeout=1):
    received = b""
    t0 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t0 < timeout:
        data = session.read_very_eager()
        if data:
            received += data
            t0 = time.time()
    return received.decode()

def write_and_read(session, command):
    time.sleep(1)
    session.write(command.encode() + b"\r\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    reply = read(session)
    print(reply)


session = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.200.10", 9000, 20)
command = "$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.200.53"

write_and_read(session, command)
write_and_read(session, command)
```

As you see the same command ("$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.200.53") is executed twice. But only the first time it works and I get the expected output.

The output I get is

```
Requesting radar report from 192.168.200.53...
Failed to query sensor. Is the IP correct? Is the sensor powered?

$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168
```

The first two lines is the correct response from the device. And the fourth line shows what I get when the command is executed again.

I tried already different sleeps, different reads, different timing, nothing. The second command just does not get through (?). It varies however in the response I get. Thhey can be

```
$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168
$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.2
$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.
```

etc. It is always some random number of characters missing.

Is there any that issue can be fixed? Might that be related to windows 10? A colleague with the same device using windows 11 does not get this issue at all...

Here is the complete communication when I use a slightly altered code as follows:

```
def write_and_read(session, command, a, b):
    time.sleep(a)
    to_write = command.encode() + b"\r\n"
    print("WRITE: ", to_write)
    session.write(to_write)
    time.sleep(b)
    reply = session.read_until(b"\n")
    print("READ: ", reply)
    reply = session.read_until(b"\n")
    print("READ: ", reply)
    return reply

command = "$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.200.53"

with telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.200.10", 9000, 10) as session:
    write_and_read(session, command, 0, 2)
    write_and_read(session, command, 0, 2)
    session.close()
```

then the output is

```
WRITE:  b'$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.200.53\r\n'
READ:  b'\x1b[0GRequesting radar report from 192.168.200.53...\r\n'
READ:  b'Failed to query sensor. Is the IP correct? Is the sensor powered?\r\n'
WRITE:  b'$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.200.53\r\n'
```

and then it blocks indefinitely.

On windows it did work when windows was using a different network adapter ("Realtek USB GbE Family Controller #4") instead of the network adapter "Realtek USB GbE Family Controller" (which is the exact same hardware device with the same parameters).

Debug output (note: using a different command, but does not matter):

```
WRITE:  b'$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTINATION_IP,192.168.200.5\r\n'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): send b'$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTINATION_IP,192.168.200.5\r\n'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\x1b[0GDESTINATION_IP = 192.168.200.5\r\n'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): IAC WILL 1
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): IAC WILL 3
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'\x1b'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'[0G\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfa\x18\x01\xff\xf0'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): IAC DO 24
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): IAC 250 not recognized
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): IAC 240 not recognized
DESTINATION_IP = 192.168.200.5

READ:
WRITE:  b'$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTINATION_IP,192.168.200.5\r\n'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): send b'$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTINATION_IP,192.168.200.5\r\n'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'$\x1b[1D \x1b[1D$C\x1b[2D  \x1b[2D$CO\x1b[3D   \x1b[3D$CON\x1b[4D    \x1b['
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'4D$CONF\x1b[5D     \x1b[5D$CONFI\x1b[6D      \x1b[6D$CONFIG\x1b[7'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'D       \x1b[7D$CONFIG,\x1b[8D        \x1b[8D$CONFIG,S\x1b[9D '
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'        \x1b[9D$CONFIG,SE\x1b[10D          \x1b[10D$CONFIG,'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'SET\x1b[11D           \x1b[11D$CONFIG,SET,\x1b[12D         '
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'   \x1b[12D$CONFIG,SET,I\x1b[13D             \x1b[13D$CONFI'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'G,SET,IM\x1b[14D              \x1b[14D$CONFIG,SET,IMU\x1b[1'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'5D               \x1b[15D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,\x1b[16D       '
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'         \x1b[16D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,D\x1b[17D              '
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'   \x1b[17D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DE\x1b[18D                  \x1b'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'[18D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DES\x1b[19D                   \x1b[1'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'9D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DEST\x1b[20D                    \x1b[2'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'0D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTI\x1b[21D                     \x1b'
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'[21D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTIN\x1b[22D                   '
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'   \x1b[22D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTINA\x1b[23D              '
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'         \x1b[23D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTINAT\x1b[24D       '
Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'                 \x1b[24D$CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTINATI'
READ:  $CONFIG,SET,IMU,DESTINATI
READ:
```

The first write/read is correct, the second write/read does not work again...
This matches also what I can see on wireshark.

Comment: Maybe you want to use [`read_until()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until) with a line break?

Comment: Was thinking the same, read until it can see that the device is ready for new input. For instance on a Cisco device, the console will typically end with `#`. Also I do not see you close the telnet connection in the code you shared. Consider using the session in a context manager instead ex: `with telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.200.10", 9000, 20) as session: ...`

Comment: I tried `reply = session.read_until(b"\n")` or put in the expected prompt but now it even does not work the first time ... In the latter case the code blocks indefinitely although I specified a timeout of 20 seconds...

Comment: Show us the exact communication *in bytes*. So far your output does not match your code.

Comment: Output added in the question with slight altered code

Comment: Disclaimer; I don't know anything about telnet. I've checked the docs, if it hangs that means there's no avaliable data, right? Could you also set `timeout` to `read_until` and if the data is still unavaliable after the timeout; retry? Lastly, could you verify that the session is still active?

Comment: Also, so far I haven't seen any examples with `time.sleep()` so why block when the `read_until` blocks already?

Comment: Is telnet working properly from your machine? if you did this manually through the CLI without python do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried a debugger to dive into the library code to see where it gets stuck? If it turns out io blocks the program, you may try a telnet CLI\wireshark

Comment: By the way, `telnetlib` is deprecated, using `telnetlib3` instead. ref: https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#deprecated-modules

Comment: @Ter I really want to avoid telnetlib3 because of this weird and cumbersome asyncio stuff which makes my code unreadable.

Comment: @Ter Seems the complete command has been sent to the device (as checked by wireshark) but the second time I get just repeated crap back from the device.

Comment: @Alex so weird. Win10 bug?Python version?Device-side bug? No idea at all :( sry for being of much help

Comment: Did you try to set the [debug level](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.set_debuglevel) and see if gives you any useful information? So do a `session.set_debuglevel(1)` and maybe post the outputs of it again.

Comment: Thanks @Nopileos I will try that next time

Comment: What type of sensor (make, model) are you querying?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex It is a hardware device with a Realtime-Linux-OS on it to process several sensor data.

Comment: Can you see in wireshark that a new connection is created? I can imagine this weird behaviour appears if the tcp connection is reused for the second command

Comment: @PabloHenkowski I am not sure how to interpret the wireshark data as I only see some bytes going back and forth, but it does not seem a new connection is created. But I could be wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

It could be a silly answer but it worth a shot. Try with a fresh new session

```py
command = "$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.200.53"

session = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.200.10", 9000, 20)
write_and_read(session, command, 0, 2)
session.close()

session = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.200.10", 9000, 20)
write_and_read(session, command, 0, 2) 
session.close()
```

Seems that you are trying to reuse a failed previous session

Answer (score 1):

This question is hard to troubleshoot without having access to the device and the environment.

You might need to [shutdown the send part](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown) of the telnet session after you sent this:  `session.write(to_write)`.

I would also suggest wrapping the code in a `try block` and adding some error handling.

```
import socket
import telnetlib
import traceback

session = telnetlib.Telnet(host="192.168.200.10", port=9000, timeout=20)
command = "$SENSOR,STATUS,192.168.200.53"
try:
    # the encoding could be utf-8 or ascii 
    to_write = command.encode('utf-8') + "\r\n"
    session.write(to_write)
    
    # this closes the send part of the session
    session.get_socket().shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    
    reply = session.read_all(b"\n")

    # if needed you might have to decode the output
    # decoded_output = reply.decode('utf-8') # or ascii
    
    # closes the entire session
    session.close()

except socket.error as error:
    print((''.join(traceback.format_tb(error.__traceback__))))
except socket.timeout as error
    print((''.join(traceback.format_tb(error.__traceback__))))
```

Above I suggested doing some `encoding` and `decoding` in your `writes` and `reads`.  Here is why:

This is the output from the first session, where the `encoding` is correct.

> Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\x1b[0GDESTINATION_IP = 192.168.200.5\r\n'

This is the output from the second session, where the `encoding` looks to be incorrect.

> Telnet(192.168.200.10,9000): recv b'$\x1b[1D \x1b[1D$C\x1b[2D  \x1b[2D$CO\x1b[3D   \x1b[3D$CON\x1b[4D    \x1b['

Note: *\x1b[1D* in this session.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the buffer isn't being cleared properly after the first command, and so part of the second command is being lost.

You could try manually flushing the buffer after writing the first command:

```
session.write(command.encode() + b"\r\n")
session.get_socket().flush()
```

Comment: Unfortunately here I get an error "AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'flush'"

Answer (score 0):

Set a timeout for reading responses:
In the read function, you are currently using a fixed timeout value. It's better to use a longer timeout and specify the actual termination characters that indicate the end of the response. In this case, it seems that `"\r\n"` is used to terminate the response.

```py
def read(session, timeout=1):
    received = b""
    t0 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t0 < timeout:
        data = session.read_until(b"\r\n", timeout=0.1)
        if data:
            received += data
            t0 = time.time()
    return received.decode()
```

Clear the telnet buffer after each command:
Before sending a new command, try clearing the telnet buffer to avoid any remnants from the previous response

```py
def write_and_read(session, command):
    time.sleep(1)
    session.write(command.encode() + b"\r\n")
    session.read_very_eager()  # Clear the buffer
    time.sleep(1)
    reply = read(session)
    print(reply)
```

Use `read_until` for the last reply:
In the second version of your code, you're using `read_until` twice, which is a better approach to ensure you read the complete response from the device.

```py
def write_and_read(session, command, a, b):
    time.sleep(a)
    to_write = command.encode() + b"\r\n"
    print("WRITE: ", to_write)
    session.write(to_write)
    time.sleep(b)
    reply = session.read_until(b"\n")
    print("READ: ", reply)
    reply += session.read_until(b"\n")  # Read the next line as well
    print("READ: ", reply)
    return reply
```

Comment: Tried all suggestions but still does not work. It did work when windows was randomly using a different network adapter WITH THE SAME SETTINGS